# nvm alias default Node.js version is not persisting

Tags: node.js, bash, nvm

Something with my NVM is not behaving correctly. I am currently on 6.0.0 on my machine and just installed 8.0.0. I want to use 8 as the default version. I run:

```
nvm alias default node
```

And I've also tried `nvm alias default 8.0.0`.

But when I check the version, all I get is `v6.0.0`.

This happens if I open a new shell tab, stay in the current tab, or kill the terminal and start from scratch.

Strangely, 6.0.0 is not even on my list of versions:

```
nvm list
         v8.0.0
->       system
default -> node (-> v8.0.0)
node -> stable (-> v8.0.0) (default)
stable -> 8.0 (-> v8.0.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/carbon (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.8.7 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.12.3 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.9.4 (-> N/A)
```

I really have no idea what is going on here. I feel like my Bash profile must have gotten really screwed up somehow, but I'm just at a loss.

My [.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file does contain this:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

$PATH:

```
/Users/w/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/w/.rbenv/shims:/Users/w/.rbenv/shims:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/w/local/node/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/Users/w/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/w/.rbenv/shims:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/w/local/node/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/opt/ruby-enterprise-2.1.2-2010.02/bin:/opt/ruby-enterprise-2.1.2-2010.02/bin
```

Answer (score 4):

(nvm maintainer here)

v6 is your system version - not installed or managed by nvm.

Indeed, setting your default to v8 should load that on a new shell.

What’s likely happening is either:

- your profile files are sourcing *nvm.sh* with *--no-use*
- or, your profile files are monkeying with the PATH such that your system Node.js’s location appears with a higher priority than nvm’s location. Check `echo $PATH` and `which node` to confirm.

Comment: `which node`: `/Users/w/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin/node`

Comment: `echo $PATH`:  so large I have to put in the main question ^^

Comment: Thanks - so you say in your question “when you check the version” - when `which node` says the above, what does `node --version` say?

Comment: What solved it for me what that I was adding to the PATH var after I was setting .nvm in my bash_profile. I moved my .nvm stuff as the last thing in my bash_profile and now my node command respected the nvm version.

Comment: I followed the instructions here to find out which version the system was loading, so to fix I set the default to the version that I want and I ran 'nvm use default' after that I remove the old version, for my problem which was let the terminal with the most recent LTS it solved